# How to fire a JavaScript event via C++ in QWebView

Tags: javascript, c++, events, qt, qwebview

please note that I'm a complete beginner to Qt development.

I have a QWebView with a QObject added to the JavaScript window object.
How do I fire a JS event on that object?

```
view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(objName,obj);
```

I want to be able to listen to events using addEventListener.

```
window.objName.addEventListener('customEventName',function(e){ ... });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. Only nodes in a DOM tree can fire events and the object you're injecting is not a node. I suggest you consider using the signal-slot mechanism instead. You can connect a slot in JS to a signal that you'll be emitting in your C++ code:

```
window.objectName.signalName.connect(slot);
```

slot is just an JS function, that you'll declare in the JS part of your code:

```
function slot(arg1, arg2, ...)
{
}
```

It takes as many arguments as are declared in the signal's signature.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent project I used the following technique:

```
void VideoWebPage::urlLoaded(bool ok)
{
    static const QString javascript =
        "function installCallbacks()                                    " \
        "{                                                                  " \
        "   var videoTags = document.getElementsByTagName('object');        " \
        "   for (var i = 0; i < videoTags.length; ++i)                      " \
        "   {                                                               " \
        "        if (videoTags[i].type == 'application/x-qt-plugin')        " \
        "        {                                                          " \
        "            if (videoTags[i].playing)                              " \
        "            {                                                      " \
        "                videoTags[i].playing.connect(playingSlot); " \
        "            }                                                      " \
        "        }                                                          " \
        "    }                                                              " \
        "}                                                                  " \
        \
        "function playingSlot(videoId)                              " \
        "{                                                                  " \
        "    var playEvent=document.createEvent('Events');                  " \
        "    playEvent.initEvent('play', true, false);                      " \
        "    document.getElementById(videoId).dispatchEvent(playEvent); " \
        "}                                                                  " \
        "installCallbacks();                                            ";
    mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(javascript);
}
```

This method looks up all `<object>` tags and connects the `playing` signal to the Javascript function `playingSlot()`.
The `playingSlot()` function in its turn creates an `Event` object with the name `play` and dispatches it as an ordinary DOM event.
The HTML file then looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="text/javascript">
    void init()
    {
        document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener('play', onPlay);
    }
    void onPlay(event)
    {
        alert('playing');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
    <object id='id1' type='application/x-qt-plugin'>
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

This is of course working with Qt plugin Widgets. I did not test it with plain HTML (i.e. where no Qt plugins are used).